# reading from a file and printing double ratios in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have file which has a series of numbers : 9 1 2 1

I try to findout the ratios subsum/sum

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{ 
    double subSum = 0;
    double sum    = 13;
    double num    = 0;
    double x      = 0;
    FILE*  file   = fopen("text.txt", "r");

    while (fscanf(file, "%f", &num) > 0)
    {
        subSum = subSum + num;
        x      = subSum / sum;

        printf("%f",x);
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

but it keeps printing zeros(0.00000000000) why ???

Comment: error check after fopen.

Comment: Please, haven't you tried a debugger, or the good old `printf`'s, to see where things go wrong.  Really, this program is so simple, have you really tried everything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're passing the address of a `double` variable to a `scanf()` format that has been told to expect the address of a `float`.

```
while (fscanf(file, "%f", &num) > 0)
```

should be:

```
while (fscanf(file, "%lf", &num) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{ 
double subSum=0;
double sum=13;
int num=0;
double x=0;
FILE *file = fopen("text.txt", "r");
while(fscanf(file, "%d", &num) > 0){
    subSum=subSum+(double)num;
    x= subSum / sum;
    printf("%f",x);
    printf("\n");
 }
fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Using `%d` with a `double` is as bad as using `%f` with a `double`.  Use `%d` to read a decimal integer.  Use `%lf` to read a `double`.  And don't use `void main()`, even if the question does.  It isn't legitimate according to the C standard or the Microsoft web site.

Answer (score 0):

If your C compiler does **NOT** support "%lf", then:

```
 float  num;
 double dnum;

 // etc.

 scanf("%f", &num);

 //etc.

 dnum = (double) num;  // use dnum in calculations
```

Comment: I don't think I've ever come across a C compiler that supported `float` but did not support `double` (or vice versa).  Once upon a long time ago, there were systems without a floating point unit, and sometimes the libraries omitted all support for floating point — or used software floating point if you requested it.  But that was a _long_ time ago, in the days of 80386 (without the companion 80387 FPU), and maybe the 80486 SX chips.